# Python/Cherrypy processing file upload from Kwargs. Instance type not indexable. Trying to dump FieldStorage data

Tags: python, cherrypy, keyword-argument

I am running cherrypy and a module that receives a file and I want to dump the data to disk.
Instead of using the cherrypy expose and getting the file from my main cherrypy application I wanted to process it myself. I've been able to get to this

`print kwargs['image']`

and it dumps this to the console

`FieldStorage('image', 'Diagram1.jpeg', *raw image data*)`

How can I access the three variables there and use them in my program?

If I try to index them it says, Instance type not indexable.

I was able to get this out of `print kwargs['image'].__dict__`

```
{'fp': <cherrypy.wsgiserver.SizeCheckWrapper object at 0x23ba510>,
'disposition_options': {'name': 'image', 'filename': 'Diagram1.jpeg'},
'innerboundary': '',
'name': 'image',
'_FieldStorage__file': None,
'list': None,
'filename': 'Diagram1.jpeg',
'keep_blank_values': 1,
'headers': <rfc822.Message instance at 0x23c1830>,
'length': -1,
'done': 1,
'disposition': 'form-data',
'qs_on_post': None,
'strict_parsing': 0,
'file': <open file '<fdopen>',
mode 'w+b' at 0x23a1270>,
'outerboundary': '----WebKitFormBoundary5KJ5TEJBxEKAvcW1',
'type_options': {},
'type': 'image/jpeg'}
```

But none of it seems accessibly since it says `TypeError: not indexable`

Comment: Might have nailed it. Using `dir(kwargs['image'])` was able to find the file attribute which is a file pointer which can be read like a file. Other variables as indicated above `filename` and `type` are also of importance

Answer (score 0):

your `kwargs['image']` is a `FieldStorage` object. The `__dict__` method is a wrapper, so as you might be able to do `dict(kwargs['image'])`.